# Using a connector with Helm-installed Kafka/Confluent

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have installed Kafka on a local Minikube by using the Helm charts https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts following these instructions https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/cp-helm-charts/docs/index.html like so:

```
helm install -f kafka_config.yaml confluentinc/cp-helm-charts --name kafka-home-delivery --namespace cust360
```

The kafka_config.yaml is almost identical to the default yaml, with the one exception being that I scaled it down to 1 server/broker instead of 3 (just because I'm trying to conserve resources on my local minikube; hopefully that's not relevant to my problem).

Also running on Minikube is a MySQL instance. Here's the output of `kubectl get pods --namespace myNamespace`:

[image]

I want to connect MySQL and Kafka, using one of the connectors (like [Debezium MySQL CDC](https://www.confluent.io/connector/debezium-mysql-cdc-connector/), for instance). In the instructions, it says:

> **Install your connector**
>
> Use the Confluent Hub client to install this
>   connector with:
>
> `confluent-hub install debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:0.9.2`

Sounds good, except 1) I don't know which pod to run this command on, 2) None of the pods seem to have a confluent-hub command available.

Questions:

1. Does confluent-hub not come installed via those Helm charts?
2. Do I have to install confluent-hub myself?
3. If so, which pod do I have to install it on?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but shouldn’t the connector be installed in the `kafka-connect` pod? You also may want to take a look at Strimzi. It provides a kube native way to roll Kafka clusters on k8s.

Comment: See "Install a Kafka Connect plugin automatically" -- https://rmoff.net/2018/12/15/docker-tips-and-tricks-with-ksql-and-kafka/ i.e. Change the command of the Connect container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally this should be configurable as part of the `helm` script, but unfortunately it is not as of now. One way to work around this is to build a new Docker from Confluent's Kafka Connect Docker image. Download the connector manually and extract the contents into a folder. Copy the contents of this to a path in the container. Something like below.

Contents of Dockerfile

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.2.1
COPY <connector-directory> /usr/share/java
```

`/usr/share/java` is the default location where Kafka Connect looks for plugins. You could also use different location and provide the new location (`plugin.path`) during your `helm` installation.

Build this image and host it somewhere accessible. You will also have to provide/override the image and tag details during the `helm` installation.

[Here](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/e17565cd5a6985a594155b12b08068cb5882e51f/charts/cp-kafka-connect/values.yaml) is the path to the `values.yaml` file. You can find the `image` and `plugin.path` values here.

Answer (score 3):

Just an add-on to Jegan's comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049585/6002912

You can choose to do the Dockerfile below. Recommended.

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-server-connect-operator:5.4.0.0

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql:1.0.0
```

Or you can use a Docker's multi-stage build instead.

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-server-connect-operator:5.4.0.0

COPY --from=debezium/connect:1.0 \
    /kafka/connect/debezium-connector-postgres/ \
    /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-connector-postgres/
```

This will help you to save time on getting the right jar files for your plugins like debezium-connector-postgres.

From Confluent documentation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/extending.html#create-a-docker-image-containing-c-hub-connectors

Answer (score 2):

The Kafka Connect pod should already have the confluent-hub installed. It is that pod you should run the commands on.

Comment: If the pod restarts, that connector will be gone, though

Comment: Ignoring @cricket_007's question for the moment (although that might be problematic) - when I run bash on that pod, I enter confluent-hub as a command, and I get "command not found"

Answer (score 1):

The cp kafka connect pod has 2 containers, one of them is a cp-kafka-connect-server container.That container has confluent-hub installed.You can login into that container and run your connector commands there.To login into that container, run the following command:

```
kubectl exec -it {pod-name} -c cp-kafka-connect-server -- /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

As of latest version of chart, this can be achieved using `customEnv.CUSTOM_SCRIPT_PATH`

See [README.md](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect#running-custom-scripts)

Script can be passed as a [secret](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect#secrets) and mounted as a [volume](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect#volumes)

Comment: may you extend your answer? I feel this is the correct track but cant manage to do alone. Thanks!